# how to extract extract the weight number without g using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>What i have</p>
<input value="1475g - 1500g" /><br>
<p>what do i need.</p>

<input style="width:50px;" value="1475" /><span>g - </span><input style="width:50px;" value="1500" /><span>g</span>


</body>
</html>
```

### Description

1. From the above code in first text box i have been setting value of '1475g - 1500g' but i need to do is show only the weight numbers in two different input box

### for example

1. string val =  1475g - 1500g;
2. string Separated_value1=1475;
3. string Separated_value2=1500;

Comment: basic regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split and replace.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input").value; // add an ID or class or something, this is just for demo purposes

const [ seperated1, seperated2 ] = input.replace(/g/g, "").split(" - "); // First regular expression removes all "g"s from the string. Split turns the string into an array using " - " as a delimiter

console.log(seperated1, seperated2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
let val = '1475g - 1500g';
val = val.replace(/g| /g, '');
val = val.split('-');
console.log(val[0], val[1]);
```